# Unable to create ec2 instance using python boto3 in vs code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```py
import boto3

aws_mag_con = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')


newec2 = aws_mag_con.client('ec2','us-east-1c',aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxx')

conn = newec2.run_instances(InstanceType="t2.micro",MaxCount=1,MinCount=1,ImageId="ami-0e1d30f2c40c4c701")
```

Tried to create instance by running the above boto3 script. It is failing with below error. Any help on this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 403, 
in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 525, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, 
in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AEE1E48E80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\va20054093\Desktop\Stud\Python\.vscode\.vscode\runinstance.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn = newec2.run_instances(InstanceType="t2.micro",MaxCount=1,MinCount=1,ImageId="ami-0e1d30f2c40c4c701")
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 725, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 104, in 
make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 138, in 
_send_request
    while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 254, in 
_needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 357, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 316, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__      
    return self._check_caught_exception(
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exceptionexception
    raise caught_exception
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 201, in _do_get_response  
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 270, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\va20054093\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 432, in send
    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1c.amazonaws.com/"

The **region** is named `us-east-1`, while an AZ is named `us-east-1c`.

The error is in this line:

```py
newec2 = aws_mag_con.client('ec2','us-east-1c',aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Change `us-east-1c` into `us-east-1`.

Comment: **Side-note:** You should NOT store your Access Key and Secret Key in your source code. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a configuration file. You can store the region there, too. Then, you can simply use `client('ec2')` and there is less risk of your credentials leaking out (eg when checking into a source code repository).